# Bot to change the role colour produces no errors but does not change the color

Tags: discord.py

I am using the Discord API to make a bot that changes the role colour. When I run this code it produces no errors but does not change the color

```
import discord
import time
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

colors = [0xFF0000, 0xF0A804, 0xFFFF00, 0x008000, 0x0000FF, 0x800080]
@bot.command()
async def rainbow(ctx):
    username = ctx.message.author
    print(username)
    roleid = 123
    role = discord.utils.get(username.guild.roles, id=roleid)
    await username.add_roles(discord.utils.get(username.guild.roles, id=roleid))
    await ctx.send('You found the Rainbow!')  #  (The rainbow hates you)
    for i in range(6):
        await role.edit(colour=discord.Colour(colors[i]))
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(colors)
    await username.remove_roles(discord.utils.get(username.guild.roles, id=roleid))
bot.run('bot token')
```

Comment: Please have a look at the [markdown syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and format your code in a codeblock

Comment: You can change `colour=discord.Colour(colors[i])` to `colour=colors[i]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this problem as well. I've noticed that whenever you modify a role, after some time, you will no longer be able to modify it anymore for some reason. I'm still trying to figure out why.